# How to get array from input and select box with jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm learning js and jquery. I will post values as array with jquery ajax and in php code I will use it with foreach loop.

```
<select name="passenger['+i+'][nationality]">
  <option value="GRE">GRE</option>
  ...
</select>

<input name="passenger['+i+'][gsm]" value="">
```

I have a form like that (for example). In php code I will use this names like that :

```
$passengers = $_POST['passenger']
foreach ($passengers as $i => $passenger) {
  echo $passenger['nationality'] . '<br>';
  echo $passenger['gsm'] . '<br>';
}
```

But to use in php I must post with jquery ajax. But I cant get array passenger with jquery to post as passenger array.

JS CODES

I need a passenger variable.

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url: link,
 type: "POST",
 data: {passenger : passenger},
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(s) {
},
 error: function() {
}
});
```

Comment: What goes wrong? What value is received by your PHP script?

Comment: Please add the javascript where you are doing the ajax-request

Comment: @showdev I will POST that array with jquery ajax. I need a variable in jquery. $.('input["passenger"]').val() like that. But it must be an array

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @PetervanderWal I have added. I suppose you understood me

Comment: like this -> `data: {passenger : $.map($('[name^="passenger"]'), function(el) {return el.value}) },`

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, it seems good but i tried die($_POST['passenger'][1]['nationaliy']) in PHP codes, says  "Uninitialized string offset".

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` first to see what it contains.

Comment: I have seen it will be useful when I create a new array with this array, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serialize` to get all the values within a form. So your JS can be:

```
$.post( link , $( "#testform" ).serialize() , function() {
     alert('Succes');
});
```

Comment: I don get all the values like that and I use json dataType. So is there a way to use like that data: {passenger : passenger} ? Can you give me a variable works like that

Comment: What values don't you get? `$.post(a, b, c)` is a shorthand for `$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: a, data: b, success: c })` so use `data: $('#form').serialize()` instead.

Comment: But i cant use foreach ($passengers as $i => $passenger) in this syntax

Comment: Do you have the elements within a `<form>`-tag on which you are calling the .serialize()? Can you post the value of an alert of the result of .serialize()? -- example http://jsfiddle.net/MP48Z/1/

Comment: I get a result like that but that is not array how can I use that in php foreach loop? -> ($passengers as $i => $passenger)